# BigInteger performance for extremely large numbers

Tags: .net, biginteger

I'm thinking about using the BigInteger class to store numbers in the range of 10-1000 MB. Does anyone have experience with this? Are there practical or implied limits for extremely large numbers?

Comment: 10 - 1000 MB? Why would you use `BigInteger` for a number that will fit comfortably in an `int`? And if you want to know how `BigInteger` performs, how about writing some simple tests to compare it with `int` and `long`. Might take you ... 10 minutes?

Comment: @JimMischel: 1000000000 will fit in an `int`, but I think the OP means 2^1000000000

Comment: 256^1000000000 in fact :)

Comment: See http://charczuk.com/2013/03/13/net-biginteger-performance.html, http://www.mrrives.com/Technology/?p=694, and http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/01/25/biginteger.aspx

Comment: Since it seems to be offline for the moment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140910033937/https://charczuk.com/2013/03/13/net-biginteger-performance.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, the [documentation for BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) says that the numbers can be of any size as long as you have enough memory to handle it.

Regular operations (add, subtract, multiply and so on) on a BigInteger are much slower (at least 50x according to some tests) than regular numeric types, but you can probably live with that.

Also, you must remember that the BigInteger type is immutable, so operations on it will yield a new instance. So adding two 10MB numbers will create a new 10MB number. It will not modify the existing instances. This may have implications for how you structure your code.

The only practical limitations is the amount of memory available on your computer and the amount of memory available to your program. This should be at least 3GB for 32bit processes, more for 64bit, so you should be able to work with the numbers you need.

Comment: I would love a mutable form of BigInteger. Does a common solution for this exist?

Answer (score 4):

There are also computational limitations. I have run into limits.

If you multiply 2 gigantic numbers, the time it takes to calculate them squares, plus some overhead. So if you did a multiplication on numbers that are 7 times larger than your previous calculation, it will take about 50X the amount of time. If you make them 1000 times larger, then it'll take about 1000000+ times longer.

Start doing loops of that and you'll realize the program may never finish in your lifetime

Comment: If you run out of memory as Rune Grimstad pointed out, I know there's a way to allocate more memory for your java programs but you'd have to look that up because I don't remember how.

Comment: Yes, this is something to take into account. It'll primarily be used for division, I suspect it has even worse runtime behavior than multiplication.